# Master branch is ahead of feature branch

Tags: git

My master branch is one step ahead of current feature branch. What happened is I carved 2 feature branches (A,B) out of main branch,

1. worked on a feature branch'A', stashed changes as another feature has become priority.
2. worked on 'B' feature branch, committed those changes to feature, merged feature branch 'B' with master.

Now master branch is one step ahead of feature branch'A'.
I have used `git pull <remote_branch_name> master` but getting error: `fatal: 'origin/features/A' does not appear to be a git repository`. Not sure how to get those changes.

Comment: `git pull <remote_branch_name> master` seems odd.  Normally you would just `git pull`  What happens when you do that?

Comment: is there any problem with master branch being ahead?

Comment: Are you trying to update A with the new changes to master? You need to merge master into A. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Comment: @jmargolisvt: when I use git pull, it says already up-to-date. But I don't see changes from master branch. I need changes from my master merged with current branch.

Comment: @mangusta: while merging branch, it will be difficult to merge changes if master branch is ahead.

Comment: @schwern: I am trying to update master branch changes to feature branch A, not other way.

Comment: If you stashed changes instead of committing them, then changing back to the branch won't have brought your changes back. Have you popped the changes back out of the stash?

Comment: `master branch changes to feature branch A` - then you do `switch` (check-out in SVN terms) into branch A, and being in branch A you run `merge` from `master`. That is the normal modus operandi

Comment: Haven't popped stash changes yet, when I stay ```git stash list```, I see ```stash@{0}: WIP on features/A: e09459b Merge pull request #32 from feature/B```

Comment: Then do `git stash pop` to get them back out of the stash. If you're working on a branch, it typically makes sense to commit the change to the branch instead of stashing.

Comment: I have popped those changes, but how do i merge my current feature branch and master branch which is one step ahead. Merge with conflicts, suggested?

Comment: If features A and B change the same code, then you'll have to resolve those conflicts at some point

Comment: Got it, I hate conflicts.

Comment: Read about [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) then forget about it completely (use `git fetch` and `git rebase` or `git merge` but only if needed). Or always use it with `--rebase`, but only after you understand what it does. `git pull` is the most frequent source of confusion for newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the feature branch with latest master branch do

```
git rebase origin/master
```

If any merge conflict occurs then resolve it. if not then you are lucky :).